# How to edit pandas dataframe inside a function which can also keep changes outside the function in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Tried creating dummies function which creates dummies and concatenates original df with dummies df. when a dataframe is passes through the function, I dont see any changes in df!

```
def get_dummies(df, col):
    colLabel = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
    df = pd.concat([df, colLabel], axis=1)

get_dummies(train_set1, 'jobtype')
```

train_set1 wont change!

Comment: You did not return anything

Comment: Why would you go searching for hacks when you can just return the result?

Comment: even if I used return, train_set1 didn't change!

Comment: Then you forget to assign it back , train_set1 =get_dummies(train_set1, 'jobtype')

Comment: I just need the train_set1 with with dummy vairables concatenated inside the function! This should change the train_set1 dataframe outside the function!

Comment: @vivekreddydevi this is a terrible design choice, btw. As a general rule, I consider functions that mutate their inputs as an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need the function to `return` the frame and assign it back:

```
def get_dummies(df, col):
    colLabel = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
    df = pd.concat([df, colLabel], axis=1)
    return df

train_set1 = get_dummies(train_set1, 'jobtype')
```

If you're absolutely insistent on doing it the way you've asked, you could potentially assigning the `DataFrame` a `__name__` attribute, and updated the frame in the `globals()` dict of variables **(definately not advised though!)**:

```
def get_dummies(df, col):
    colLabel = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
    new_df = pd.concat([df, colLabel], axis=1)
    globals()[df.__name__] = new_df

train_set1.__name__ = 'train_set1'
get_dummies(train_set1, 'jobtype')
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but I was trying to see if I can just assign the changes inside the function.

So when I call get_dummies(), it will change the train_set1!

Comment: @vivekreddydevi you can, but why do want that?

Comment: This, of course, assumes that the function will only be called from the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Concat returns a copy of the data, so normally the operation is not in place.
A number of pandas functions have a "in_place" argument. Set this to true, if you want to modify the dataset, rather than get a copy.
Concat does not have such a argument, but an "copy" argument. Try setting that to false.

Comment: def get_dummies(df, col):
        colLabel = pd.get_dummies(df[col])
        df = pd.concat([df, colLabel], axis=1, copy=False)

  get_dummies(train_set1, 'jobtype')


tried this, still the train_set1 remains the same!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' `pandas.concat` function by default copies the data frame on concatenation. Essentially, this generates a new data frame which is stored in your local `df` variable and replaces the reference to the original data frame passed from outside. As a consequence, upon assignment to `df`, you don't change the original data frame anymore but replace it with a new one *only inside the function*.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

> **pandas.concat**(objs, axis=0, join='outer', join_axes=None, ignore_index=False, keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False, sort=None, **copy=True**)

Setting `copy=False` in your call would modify the data frame in place and not replace the reference by a new data frame which would never be able to leave the function scope.